# Correct :last-child CSS3 syntax for last li of ul>li>ul>li structure

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to make 2nd level and very last `li` hidden by `display:none;` command. However I couldn't achieve with trials below:

my `ul` `li` structure

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <li>* * *</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <li>* * *</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <li>dynamic content</li>
            <!-- I need to make li below hidden-->
            <li>* * *</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

unsuccessful trials:

made all `* * *` hidden -> `li ul:last-child li:last-child{display:none;}`

made all `* * *` hidden also -> `li ul li:last-child{display:none;}`

can you please correct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do what you want:

```
ul li:last-child ul li:last-child{display:none;}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4C53Z/)